# Excel Formula to calculate currency exchange rates based on Fixed Rate Table

Tags: excel, currency-exchange-rates

I have a fixed currency exchange rate table (columns A to C) for 10 different currencies to CAD in Excel as follows:

[image: Fixed Rates to CAD]

I would like to know if there is a formula that I can use under Column H to populate all the different combinations of currencies and give me the exchange rates based on the table mentioned above:

[image: All combinations]

Comment: @ScottCraner, he may not just want the `VLOOKUP`.  I guess what he wants is to have all the conversion rates computed based on the first table.  So USD to BBD will need to use USD to CAD and BBD to CAD columns to do it.

Comment: correct, my second table has all the possible combinations (100 rows) of exchange rates. (ie AUD to EUR, SAR to GBP, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E2,C:C)/SUMIF(A:A,F2,C:C)
```

[image]

Comment: @AlvinWong If worked for you please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.